# Proxy : How to parse https request and response coming from socket connection

Tags: java, sockets, https, proxy

i'm creating a **simple proxy** in java.
What i'm doing is use **ServerSocket** to start it on a specific port and route the requests i've receive to a list of external proxies.
So, **teorically** i don't need parse the request and response, simply takes bytes recived and route them to the final destination.
My objective is to choose the destination proxy with some application logic.
In order to do this it wold be very usefull to know :

- Ip of the client that connect to my proxy
- Http response code that i receive from the final proxy

For a "normal" http connection this is possibile. When i read the data i can parse it and get the information i need.
With a https connection, all data are encrypted so i think this is not possibile. Anyone can confirm this and eventually suggest a way to bypass this "*problem*"?

Here some code as an example :

```
//start my proxy
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(portNum);
Socket client= ss.accept();

//connection arrived : get pointer to streams
final InputStream from_client = client.getInputStream();
final OutputStream to_client = client.getOutputStream();

//Try to open socket to destination proxy
Socket server = null;
try {
    server = new Socket([destination proxy host], [destination proxy port]);
} catch (IOException e) {
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(to_client));
    out.println("Proxy server cannot connect to " + opt.getProxyHost() + ":" + opt.getProxyPort() + ":\n" + e));
    out.flush();
    client.close();

}

some stuff ...

//get streams from destination 
final InputStream from_server = server.getInputStream();
final OutputStream to_server = server.getOutputStream();

//in a separate Thread :

try {
        //transfer bytes from client to server ( java >= 9 )
        //**NOTE : the https connection is encrypted, is not possibile to parse the request received, just route it**
    from_client.transferTo(to_server);

} catch (IOException e) {

    //Manage exception
}
```

The response have the same problem :

```
int bytes_read;
try {

//**NOTE : the https connection is encrypted, is not possibile to parse the response received, just route it back**

    from_server.transferTo(to_client);

} catch (IOException e) {

  //Manage exception
}
```

Thanks
Davide

Comment: This is the whole reason for HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks tkausl! Yes i know, but i'm not an expert on socket programming and i want to know if someone have workaround o some tips. What i need is a way to identify client and the request (ex: uri ) not to decript the body